# how to use 3x size in iPhone 6/6plus

Tags: ios

I have some image resources, such as toolbar-1@2x.png toolbar-2@2x.png toolbar-1@3x.png toolbar-2@3x.png, I find that the 3x images can't autosize for iPhone 6/6plus, how can I set the 3x size images for iPhone 6/6plus? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just drag your images to your `xcassets` file in your project. Xcode handles all the sizing stuff.

Not really directly relevant but as a known issue, you cannot use jpg files in your `xcassets` file on iOS7.

Answer (score 0):

*I hope you know what is `Images.xcassets` , you should use asset catalog for adding all your 1x,2x and 3x images.*

**As per apple doc:-**

> An asset catalog can include:
>
> ```
> Image sets: Used for most types of images, an image set contains all the versions, or representations, of an image that are necessary
> ```
>
> to support various devices and scale factors.
>
> ```
> App icons: App icon sets contain all the representations of the icon that iOS apps must provide to be displayed on a device’s Home
> ```
>
> screen and in the App Store.
>
> ```
> Launch images: Launch image sets contain all the representations of the static launch image that iOS apps must provide to be
> ```
>
> temporarily displayed when the app is launched.